# Tanstack react query useInfiniteQuery data is not updated client data, the server returns the updated data

Tags: react-native, react-query, tanstackreact-query, trpc.io, trpc

I have a problem using react query with my trpc api.
I am using an infiniteQuery, the staletime is 0, when I come on the screen the query is fetching and the server returns the updated data but in client side the data still contains old data I don't understand why since the staletime is 0 it should update the cache with the new data:

this is the query I sent:

```
export const useMyNotifications = () =>
  api.user.getNotifications.useInfiniteQuery(
    {
      limit: 20,
    },
    {
      getNextPageParam: lastPage => lastPage.nextCursor,
    },
  );
```

This is my procedure:

```
getNotifications: protectedProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        cursor: z.string().nullish(),
        limit: z.number().min(1).max(20).default(20),
      }),
    )
    .query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      const { cursor, limit } = input;
      const notifications = await ctx.db.notification.findMany({
        take: limit + 1,
        where: {
          userId: ctx.user?.uid as string,
        },
        orderBy: [{ createdAt: 'desc' }, { id: 'desc' }],
        cursor: cursor ? { id: cursor } : undefined,
        include: {....}
     })
   })
 )
```

The react query config:

```
const [queryClient] = useState(
    () =>
      new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
          queries: {
            cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 24 hours
          },
        },
      }),
  );

const [trpcClient] = useState(() =>
    api.createClient({
      transformer: superjson,
      links: [
        httpLink({
          url: `${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/trpc`,
          async headers() {
            return {
              authorization: await getToken(),
            };
          },
        }),
      ],
    }),
  );

  const [asyncStoragePersister] = useState(() =>
    createAsyncStoragePersister({
      storage: AsyncStorage,
      retry: removeOldestQuery,
    }),
  );

return (
    <api.Provider client={trpcClient} queryClient={queryClient}>
      <PersistQueryClientProvider
        client={queryClient}
        persistOptions={{ persister: asyncStoragePersister }}>
        {children}
      </PersistQueryClientProvider>
    </api.Provider>
  );
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: would be good to see a minimal codesandbox reproduction of this. Maybe it's a race condition between async storage persister restoring the state and refetches, but it shouldn't be...

Comment: Hello @TkDodo thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for the late reply. The problem is not due to the storage I tried without storage, it is the same, It is very weird, I really don't understand, when I come the first time on the screen it works but after the data become stale it fetched, the server side data is okay. The problem seems to be in infiniteQuery side since useQuery works fine. I don't know how I can do a codesandbox since it is a big project and not open source. Thanks again

Comment: you narrow down the project, you stub out relevant api requests with `Promise.resolve` and then you show that the issue exists in react-query in a minimal way. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again @TkDodo. When Added these options it works :

```
export const useMyNotifications = () =>
  api.user.getNotifications.useInfiniteQuery(
    {},
    {
      getNextPageParam: lastPage => lastPage?.nextCursor,
      keepPreviousData: true,
      staleTime: 0,
      refetchOnMount: 'always',
      refetchOnWindowFocus: 'always',
      notifyOnChangeProps: ['data'],
    },
  );
```

I am trying to figure out why exactly.